# C++ pattern output

Tags: c++, matrix, output

I am working on a project that requires me to have a loop output a pattern into the console.

I have to use a for loop in my code. I've gotten to a point where I can only get half of the pattern onto the screen but the rest does not appear in the console.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int i, j;

  for (i=5; i>=1; i--)
  {
     for (j=1; j != i; j++)
     {
        cout << "5";
        cout << "#";
     cout << endl;
     }
  }
return 0;
}
```

So this code outputs:

```
####5
###5
##5
#5
5
```

But I need it to output:

```
####5
###5#
##5##
#5###
5####
```

How would I change my code to get it to show that output?

I hope that makes sense, 
Thank you

Comment: Please look at your inner loop.  Now, imagine you are on any line except the first.  Pretend you are the computer executing these instructions and write down on paper what happens.  I expect someone is going to come along and just give you the answer by treating this as a fun "ooh I can do this" exercise, but if that happens you are going to learn far less about thinking like a programmer than if you worked it out.

Comment: "So this code outputs:" -- no, it doesn't. The shown code always outputs "5" followed by "#". Every "5" is followed by the "#". The claimed output that results from executing this program doesn't match the code. Your question is unanswerable, because the shown code is not the real code that results in the claimed output, or there is a typographical error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

your `internal loop` is the one that tracks moving `5` from *right* to *left*

```
  for (i=5; i >= 1; i--) {
     for (j=1; j <= 5; j++) {
        cout << (( i == j ) ? "5" : "#");
     }
     cout << endl;
  }
```

removing the fancy things

```
for (i=5; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (j=1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        if( i == j ) 
           cout << "5";
        else
           cout << "#";
      }
         cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

Let's be clear: the OP's code is completely wrong and I cannot understand how it works and produces that output, so I wrote it from scratch.

Before_edit:

I can't understand how your code work, so I rewrite that from scratch.

```
#include <iostream>

void output_sharp(int cnt)
{
    while (cnt != 0)
        std::cout << "#";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 4; i != 5; ++i, --j) {
        output_sharp(j - i);
        std::cout << "5";
        output_sharp(4 - j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I can't understand how your code work, so I rewrite that from scratch."_ -- good luck finding a job in software development! ;)

Comment: @paddy Have a look at the OP's code. Can u understand how it produces that output? I can't. So I write that from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j;

  for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
  {
     for(int z=0; z<5;z++){
         if(z==i){
             cout <<"5";
         }
         else{
         cout <<"#";
         }
     }
     cout <<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}

####5
###5#
##5##
#5###
5####
```

Chears :-)